# RedirectToAction("Index", "User") captured by custom RouteHandler,but RedirectPermanent("/user/index/") Normal Running

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

RedirectToAction("Index", "User") captured by custom RouteHandler,but RedirectPermanent("/user/index/") no problem

In a action the codes like that

```
 public ActionResult AddSimpleDescription(TSimpleDescription entity2, string url, string which)
        {
 //my colds

return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
}
```

In global file I register a custom RouteHandler like below

```
public static void RegisterHandler(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.Add("upload_file",
            new Route("upfile/bkup/nsksjskjs/", new HHT.Utility.Components.CompressRoutHandler()));

        }
```

when mycode run complete in action AddSimpleDescription, then excute RedirectToAction("Index", "User") and the page goto the url "http://localhost:59000/upfile/bkup/nsksjskjs?action=Index&controller=User" 
Why? How can I resolve this proplem?

Index action code

public ActionResult Index(string param, string id)
        {
            try
            {
                getUserName();

```
            //ViewBag.RCount = remindbll.GetCount(int.Parse(User.Identity.Name));
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Render(3, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the code of the `Index` action please , you can check using a tool like fiddle2 to see if it goes to `Index` first then redirect or it doesn't go there

Comment: public ActionResult Index(string param, string id)
        {
            try
            {
                getUserName();
                if (param == null)
               
                //ViewBag.RCount = remindbll.GetCount(int.Parse(User.Identity.Name));
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Render(3, ex.Message);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that it's because you are working with custom routes, I don't know if "upload_file" is your unique route or not... but when you work with custom routes must specify the route that you want use otherwise it will use the default route

You have this follow register route...

```
public static void RegisterHandler(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.Add("default_route", new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "controller", action = "action", id = UrlParameter.optional})

        routes.Add("upload_file",
        new Route("upfile/bkup/nsksjskjs/", new HHT.Utility.Components.CompressRoutHandler()));

    }
```

so you must tell which route that should use

```
return RedirectToRoute("default_route");
```